# Bootstrap javascript breaks links

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-waypoints, stellar.js

I'm developing a WordPress site using the following technologies:

- stellarjs
- waypoints.js
- evidently jquery
- jquery easing
- jquery masonry
- jquery imagesloaded
- prettyPhoto
- and bootstrap

Some combination of these scripts makes it that the links inside the content don't work, but only when I include bootstrap.js (I've narrowed it down by the process of elimination). If I click on a link, nothing happens, as if preventDefault is applied.

I've tried to find out if these scripts are incompatible buty i got no revelant search results.

The developed site can bee found here: [http://retesz.w.pw/](http://retesz.w.pw/en/#slide2). try clicking on tha facebook/youtube/linkedin links from the menu or any other link inside the content. Although if an image is opened inside the prettyPhoto modal, the links in the image description work.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR; **update to the newest bootstrap version**.

I would imagine that you have sorted this out by now. However, I've recently encountered the same issue when using a theme based on bootstrap 3.0 and 3.1

I did not have time to debug it properly, especially since it's now fixed, but the links are blocked by preventDefault() in the following part of bootstrap code:

```
  $(document).on('click.bs.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function (e) {
    [...]
    if ($this.is('a')) e.preventDefault()
```

This issue is easily fixed at present **update to the newest bootstrap version**.